# How do I monitor what Javascript is being triggered when I click an element in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, web

Working with another developer's code: When I click an element on his page and a Javascript/jQuery event is triggered, how do I monitor what JS is being triggered? I am somewhat familiar with event listening but I was under the impression that you must either know the variable being declared or a line of code that is being executed. I don't know either as I am trying to find it within his source in order to add additional functionality and refactor it. Thank you.

Example: He has an "accordion flyout" which reveals more text when you click on a plus symbol and then hides it when you click it again. I want to improve it so that the plus symbol changes to a minus symbol by adding a line of JS that modifies the CSS background-image. I just don't know where he has embedded his functionality.

EDIT: Interested in either a method involving debugging tools for web browser OR a programmatic solution involving code. I'm assuming the solution will involve a debugging tool as I don't know where to find previous developer's JS code in this large application.

Comment: Are you asking for code to do this, or how to use a browser's developer tools?

Comment: I would be interested in either, whatever leads to the source code that holds the event information or functionality so that I can modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press F12 or right click on the webpage and choose inspect element ( doesn't have to be the element you're checking).

Then you can use several tools:

1) Timeline tab and the recording button which will show all the events that are happening

then when you have identified the process using the above

go to

2) Sources tab and subtab Content Scripts and search for the function or variable or script file you're interested in ( use ctrl + F to search in script files as it greatly saves time)

P.S.

Using chrome

Comment: Timeline in Chrome is very helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Firebug you could install an additional addon called Firequery. It enhances the HTML View with Events on the elements.

Answer (score -1):

You can add to your Javascript to output to console. You can also monitor it using F12 key on most browsers. In some browsers, you may need to enable debugging and/or javascript debugging.

Comment: It's another developer's code and OP doesn't know where the right block is. If they knew where to add a `console` statement they'd already have the answer to this question

Comment: ...interesting. OP states he is familiar with event listening and states "I don't know either as I am trying to find it within his source in order to add additional functionality and refactor it."... therefore leading to the answer to the Javascript to output to "console", so it can be viewed in the console using F12 key. Note: You may want to re-read what the OP asked.

Comment: Well, quite. If he doesn't know where to find the code being executed, where are you saying he should put the `console.log` line?

Comment: Two more answers you can down vote that mention how to view the console. Feel free to troll them too...