# how to debug javascript element (like a button)

Tags: javascript, debugging, web

It sound like a simple debug question but I cannot find the solution.

On a web browser like chrome, in the dev panel, I would like to inspect an element (like a button) and then ask chrome to find the corresponding javascript events on the page / file (in order to place breakpoint or to look at the code).

How can I do that ? (without fireing the event and checking the timeline as proposed by @dev3078 in this post [How do I monitor what Javascript is being triggered when I click an element in a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912969/how-do-i-monitor-what-javascript-is-being-triggered-when-i-click-an-element-in-a)). I'd like to have, as in IDE, a 'goto javascript events declaration' !

Comment: Have you looked at the [Event Listeners panel on the Elements inspector](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/command-line/events?hl=en#view-event-listeners-registered-on-dom-elements)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to sources, on the right side you'll see a dropdown called Event Listener Breakpoints, expand Mouse Events and select click, when you click on your Dom button, dev tools will go into debugging mode inside the first function called after the click event, you can also choose more events other than click